# クラウドサービスでJSON等のデータを投げたらPDFを返してくれるようなサービスはありませんでしょうか？

Tags: pdf

クラウドサービスでJSON等のデータを投げたらPDFを返してくれるようなサービスはありませんでしょうか？
現在ウェブシステム開発時には何かしらのPDF生成モジュールを使ってXY座標を計算しながらPDF帳票を生成しています。
非常に生産性が悪いと思いますので、グラフィカルに帳票をデザインしてJSONデータ等をPOSTしたら自動的にPDFデータを生成してくれるようなサービスはありませんでしょうか？

※補足
Windowsデスクトップのツール等はいくつか見つけているのですが、デザイン含めクラウドで完結出来るツールを探しています。理由はシステム利用者の方がご自身でデザインの調整を行う事が多い為です。

Comment: 単純に「見た目そのまま」に変換するものであれば世に溢れているはずなので、JSON データや期待する PDF の結果についてもう少し詳しい説明があると回答が付きやすい気がします。(レイアウト指示のようなものを出したいということでしょうか？)

Comment: 日本語ではないですが、こんなサイトのことでしょうか？ [PDF Generator API](https://pdfgeneratorapi.com/), [Create PDF files from json or csv data.](https://rapidapi.com/quodlibet/api/create-pdf-files-from-json-or-csv-data), [PDF Generation Made Easy Using Ready-Made Templates and JSON to PDF API](https://advicement.io/blog/pdf-generation-made-easy-using-ready-made-templates-and-json-to-pdf-api), [Try JSON to PDF API Call in 3 Steps](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-api-call)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！なるほどーこんなのがあるのですね。英語ではありますが、初めて見るサービスばかりなので凄く勉強になります！

Comment: @cubick さんありがとうございます！JSONデータは汎用的なデータの意味で、デザインは元々別のファイル（テンプレートPDF等）で用意出来る出来るイメージでした…。説明がヘタクソですいません。